# How to identify where's the chunks' boundaries?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't have some client to actually view the chunk boundaries and I don't want to use one, so I want to do it by hand.

Are there any clues how to identify the chunk's boundaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Java Edition, press F3+G (press and hold F3, and while holding it, press G). This toggles display of chunk borders.